# How to create list with form to track people responses in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, survey

I want to create a list with form to collect the user response or feedback on usage of a Software (say "X software). Like,

1. What went well while using the software?
2. What did not go well?
3. Any other comments?

Any one please suggest me. Its very urgent requirement

Comment: I am afraid the question is bit unclear. Can you please explain more.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should better know abut SharePoint Survey feature,

Quick steps:

1. Click Settings , and then click Add an app.
2. On the Your Apps page, look for and click the Survey icon.
3. Type a name for the survey and Create it.
4. You will see your Survey listed in the 'Site Contents' page.
5. Click on the “Survey” we just created.
6. The next screen should take you to the survey you just created.
7. Click on “Settings” and select “Add Questions”.
8. Start typing you first Survey Question.

Refer the below links which will give you more details about SharePoint Survey,

- [article 1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba)
- [article 2](http://www.siteactions.net/2012/11/08/how-to-quickly-build-a-survey-using-sharepoint-2013/)
- [article 3](https://www.collaboris.com/blogs/collaboris-blog/mark-jones/2012/11/03/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-survey-in-under-5-minutes#.V3Nr3bV-McQ)